# Proving a set is a metric space

Tags: metric-spaces, proof-writing

I am currently doing questions from Kaplansky's *Set Theory And Metric Spaces.* I come to seek validation on my answers because my book does not have an answer key. I am looking on ways to strengthen my proof, as well.

Let $\{a, b\} = M$. Define $D(a, a) = D(b, b) = 0, D(a, b) = D(b, a) = r$, where $r$ is a real number such that $r > 0$. Prove $M$ is a metric space relative to the function $D.$

Q) The conditions for the distance between the same points being $0$ and the distance between $a$ and $b$ being positive reals are satisfied.

Here I am puzzled; is this all I needed to prove? Is there something I am missing?

Comment: We need to verify $D(a,b)=D(b,a)$ and we also need to verify the Triangle Inequality. Both are very easy, but in principle it must be done.

Comment: How can we verify the triangle inequality when $a, b$ are the only members of the set? Aren't 3 members needed?

Comment: In the triangle inequality, $D(x,z) \leqslant D(x,y) + D(y,z)$, it is not necessary that $x,y,z$ are distinct. Having two of them equal (or even all three) makes the verification easier.

Comment: No, three distinct members are not needed. In your case, when you are trying to prove that $d(x,y)+d(y,z)\ge d(x,z)$, the $x,y,z$ cannot be all distinct. If $x=z$ the inequality is trivial since then $d(x,z)=0$. If say $x=y$, again verification is easy. Nothing in the triangle inequality says the objects have to be distinct, though admittedly the triangle inequality is obvious when the objects are not all distinct.

Comment: To verify $D(a, b) = D(b, a)$, isn't it already done in the question? Both equal $r$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only non-trivial (by definition) axiom of a metric space you need to check is the triangle inequality. Let $x_1,x_2,x_3\in M$. By definition, either $D(x_i,x_j)=0\mbox{ or }r$.

Suppose $D(x_1,x_2)=0$ and $D(x_2,x_3)=0$. Then $x_1=x_2=x_3$ and so $$D(x_1,x_3)=0\leq D(x_1,x_2)+D(x_2,x_3).$$

Suppose $D(x_1,x_2)=0$ and $D(x_2,x_3)=r$. Then $x_1=x_2$ and so $$D(x_1,x_3)=D(x_2,x_3)=r\leq D(x_1,x_2)+D(x_2,x_3).$$

Suppose $D(x_1,x_2)=r$ and $D(x_2,x_3)=r$. Then w.l.o.g. let $x_1=a$, and so $x_2=b$ because $D(x_1,x_2)=r$, and so then also $x_3=a$ because $D(x_2,x_3)=r$. Therefore $$D(x_1,x_3)=D(a,a)=0\leq D(x_1,x_2) +D(x_2,x_3).$$

So in all cases $D(x_1,x_2) +D(x_2,x_3)\geq D(x_1,x_3)$ and the triangle inequality holds.